# Treacherous ride - top half of fork points backwards, but the bottom points forward

Tags: repair, shocks

I have a Kent Glendale with dual front suspension. The top half of the fork is turned around so the right shock was installed into the left stanchion and vice-versa. and I cannot figure out how to remove the lower half of the fork. There are no screws on the outside, just a rubber stopper at the top of each stanchion tube and a nylon split washer at each joint. Looking down through the tubes, it's just a black hole for several inches.[image: mis-assembly puts wheel too far back] [image: How does this joint come apart?]

Comment: Could you provide some photos? I'm having a hard time imagining everything.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Here are 2 pictures I hope you can see.
[link](http://splendidlens.com/shoebox/Kent1.jpg)
[link](http://splendidlens.com/shoebox/Kent2.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure the fork hasn't just been bent backwards in a crash? (The curve of the fork crown looks as if it would be wrong if you turned it round. But then I'd expect there to be some visible damage at the top if it was bent back, and I can't see any, so maybe it really is an assembly problem.)

Comment: To my eyes that fork looks bent! Better bring it by a bike shop to have them check!

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be bent. Looking at [this image](http://cdn.mos.bikeradar.com/images/bikes-and-gear/components/forks-suspension/1331722287478-18pf9mq39th04-280-75.jpg) you can see that the fork looks put together properly with the concave part of crown facing towards the front of the bike. Which is exactly how this one is assembled.

Comment: I see what you mean about the concave part apparently facing in the right direction. The shocks work smoothly, so if anything is bent it could only be where the shocks are welded into sockets in the crown. I just can't see where anything has bent. Right now I think the bike would handle better if I turned the handlebars around. At least the axle would be in front of the crown tube.

Comment: I wouldn't ride it. Were the fork to fail (which is a very real possibility) you're guaranteed a trip into the pavement. Bring it to a bike shop - it is easier to fix than broken bones.

Comment: Oh my god don't ride that

Comment: A classic "ran into a parked car".  I've seen it several times.

Answer (score 2):

After a little Google research of this bike, you can see that the fork is assembled correctly. What's going on is that the crown (the part the stanchions attach to) is bent/twisted or the steer tube (the tube that runs through to the handlebars) is bent. Either way, you're going to need some mechanic work or a new fork.

On a side note, you can probably remove the stanchions from the crown, but judging by the amount of rust in your pictures, they're probably fairly stuck by now.

Comment: Many thanks to all. I will be looking for another fork. Also, I am now told that this one is a maintenance-free throw-away fork, so there never was any way to take it apart.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this bike has been run into the read of a stopped car. It may be cracked at the top of the form blades, at the crown.

REPLACE!

Answer (score 0):

That for is not mis-assembled, it is bent. It's damaged and probably dangerous to ride. Throw it away and get a new one. It will likely cost less than $100 installed. Small price to pay for your safety.